# Google Maps javascript doesn't show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heatmap, gmaps.js

I'm developing a web application with NodeJS and AngularJS. Now, I'm trying to put a heatmap with heatmapjs and [gmap plugin](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/plugin-gmaps-layer.html).

I've included the scripts in the html with my API KEY(also I'm working with Chartjs):

```js
<script src="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_APIKEY">
    </script>
    <script src="/node_modules/heatmap.js/build/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="gmaps-heatmap.js"></script>
```

I've copied [the example](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-googlemaps.html) into my angular controller:

```js
// don't forget to add gmaps-heatmap.js
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568);
// map options,
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: myLatlng
    };
// standard map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
// heatmap layer
    var heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(map,
        {
            // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
            "radius": 2,
            "maxOpacity": 1,
            // scales the radius based on map zoom
            "scaleRadius": true,
            // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
            // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries
            //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
            "useLocalExtrema": true,
            // which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
            latField: 'lat',
            // which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
            lngField: 'lng',
            // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
            valueField: 'count'
        }
    );

    var testData = {
        max: 8,
        data: [{lat: 24.6408, lng:46.7728, count: 3},{lat: 50.75, lng:-1.55, count: 1}]
    };

    heatmap.setData(testData);
```

I put the map in the HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mapita de calor
                </div>
                <canvas id="map-canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There is no errors y the console but the map into page doesn't appear, so why??

Comment: Who knows. Please post your code Daniel. Or even better post some demo that represents your issue

Comment: @MaximShoustin Now I've actualized the post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up some height and width in your html/css for the maps to appear. By default they take 0 height and 0 width.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Alankar Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8584001/alankar-anand)'s answer, You also need to have a callback method in order to initialize the map

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY& callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: So, whai Do I should insert into that method?

Comment: My bad. You can do this without a callback method. And I was able to get the map with your code. Seems your issue is with styling only. Can I see the styling block?

Comment: Styling block?? I use bootstrap.

Comment: For Google Maps, the height of the map should be explicitly set to 100%. So, you need to have this in your css. That is one thing. The other thing I noticed you are using <canvas id="map-canvas"></canvas> for the map. Change it to <div id="map-canvas"></div>.